# parameter numIter in stronglyConnectedComponents (GraphX Spark)

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-graphx

I am making myself familiar with GraphX library from Spark using the guide https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html
However, reading this (and searching the internet) I couldn't realize  what is the input parameter **numIter** of function stronglyConnectedComponents:
**def stronglyConnectedComponents(numIter: Int): Graph[VertexID, ED]**

Could you help me to understand what does it mean here and what algorithm is used for SCC by GraphX?

Comment: As far as i understand, Tarjan’s algorithm uses depth-first search and is not parallelizable.  That's why SparkX uses iterative distributed algorithm and you need to specify the number of iterations.